# backbone - how to trigger render of view after fetching all models in a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I made a loop over the models in a collection to fetch with the function fetchAll within the collection description.

```
fetchAll: function(){
    this.counter=0;
    self = this;
      for (var i=0;i<this.models.length; i++){
      this.models[i].fetch({
        success: function(){
          self.counter +=1;
          if (self.counter == self.models.length){
            alert('done');
            self.doneFetchAll = true;
          }
        }
      });

      //console.log(i);
      }
```

After the fetching is done, I see an alert and the collection property `doneFetchAll` is set to true.... but how to trigger the render of the view after this has been done?

1) is there a possibility in backbone to listen to a change in a specific attribute of the collection and if positive, call the render again?

OR

2) is there a better approach to fetch all models in the collection and THEN re render the view?

all this efforts of listening to changes have failed (whiting the `initialize: function()` of the view):

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, "change:doneFetchAll", this.render);
```

or

```
this.collection.on("change:doneFetchAll", this.render, this);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a custom event :

```
fetchAll: function(){
    this.counter=0;
    self = this;
      for (var i=0;i<this.models.length; i++){
      this.models[i].fetch({
        success: function(){
          self.counter +=1;
          if (self.counter == self.models.length){
            self.trigger('fetchAll'); // here
            self.doneFetchAll = true;
          }
        }
      });

  //console.log(i);
  }
```

and then in the `initialize: function()` :

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, "fetchAll", this.render);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just listen to "sync" event instead of fetchAll?

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render)?
```